# Show that $\left|\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\right|=r$ represents a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Suppose $|a|<1$ and $r\in (0,1)$. Show that the set of complex number $z$ satisfying $\left|\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\right|=r$ is a circle in complex plane. Find the centre and radius of this circle.

By putting $z=x+iy$ and $a=a_1+ia_2$ and then simplifying I got the result, but the process is too lengthy. I want a short and tricky way that the equation represents a circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left|\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\right|^2=r^2$$
$$(z-a)\overline{(z-a)}=r^2(z\bar{a}-1)\overline{(z\bar{a}-1)}$$
$$|z|^2-(z\bar a+\bar z a)+|a|^2=r^2(|z|^2|a|^2-(z\bar a+\bar z a)+1)$$
$$|z|^2(1-r^2|a|^2)-(z\bar a+\bar z a)(1-r^2)+(|a|^2-r^2)=0$$
Let $z=x+iy$ and $a=p+iq.$ Then this equation can be simplified to $$x^2+y^2-(px+qy)\left(\dfrac{1-r^2}{1-r^2(p^2+q^2)}\right)+\dfrac{p^2+q^2-r^2}{1-r^2(p^2+q^2)}=0.$$

Comment: I did this calculation ...But from here how I can say that this represents a circle and how detect the centre and radius ?

Comment: See my edit. That will helps you.

Comment: Oh!! Actually finally you put $z=x+iy$ and $a=p+iq$. I tried to find out the equation in the form $|z-a|=R$.

Comment: Actually $$|z-a|=r\iff |z|^2-(z\bar a+\bar z a)+(|a|^2-r^2)=0.$$ Can you find $a$ and $r$ comparing above equations? I think it will not be difficult.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from
$$\left|\dfrac{z-a}{1-\bar a z}\right|=r$$
we can get
$$\dfrac{\left|z-a\right|}{\left| z-1/{\bar a}\right|}=r\left|a\right|$$
which in language of geometry means 'point $z$ distances from two fixed points $a$ and $1/{\bar a}$ make a constant ratio (equal $r\left|a\right|$)'.

And that is a definition of a Circle of Apollonius (Wikipedia [Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle), section Circle of Apollonius) — so you have a circle (provided the RHS is not equal $1$, in which case you get a line bisecting the segment with endpoints $a$ and $1/{\bar a}$).

Comment: +1. As one acquires more mathematical tools, one should not forget about basic facts.

Comment: how do we also show that $\left|\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}\right| < 1$? (assuming $|z|<1$ and $|a|<1$)